# How to optimise a code to eliminate stopwords from a text Perl

Tags: algorithm, perl, optimization, stop-words

I have a code that read a Text file and a file that contain stopword list, but this code take a great time in the execution, how to optimise this code?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
print "choose the name of the result file\n";
my $fic = <STDIN>;

open( FIC1, ">$fic" );

my @stops;
my @file;

use File::Copy;

open( STOPWORD, "C:\\ats\\stop-ats" ) or die "Can't Open: $!\n";

@stops = <STOPWORD>;
while (<STOPWORD>)    #read each line into $_
{
    chomp @stops;     # Remove newline from $_
    push @stops, $_;  # add the line to @triggers
}



close STOPWORD;

open( FILE, "C:\\ats\\ats" ) or die "Cannot open FILE";

while (<FILE>) {
    $line = $_;

    #print  $line;
    my @words = split( /\s/, $line );
    foreach $word (@words) {
        chomp($word);
        foreach $wor (@stops) {
            chomp($wor);
            if ( $word eq $wor ) {

                #print   "$wor\n";
                $word = '';

            }
        }

        print FIC1 $word;
        print FIC1 " ";

    }
    print FIC1 "\n";
}
exit 0;
```

The code take a very long time to process a text file , how to optimise this code

Comment: `@stops = <STOPWORD>` reads the full file. `while (<STOPWPRD>)` is therefore skipped, as there's nothing else to read. `%stops = @stops` creates keys from the odd stopwords, and values from the even. Is it really what you want?

Comment: no these are mistakes, must be corrected, i only want to read the file that contains stopwrods, the words contained in @stop must be eliminated from the file FILE

Comment: There's no point in optimising code that doesn't run correctly.

Comment: But you really want to look at perlre.

Comment: As horrendous as this code is, it should mostly... kind of... sort of work. How big are your files, and how long is the program running?

Comment: Also: some sample input and output.

Comment: @choroba: sorry but the code work and it eliminates stopword, why you said this dosen't work!!! justify !! waht you said is incorrect

Comment: @MattJacob: the files are not very big 2Mo ,and 500ko , the code take many hours but not finished yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason why your code is slow is because it loops over the array of stopwords for each word in the input. The standard approach here would be to use a hash of stopwords rather than the array.

Also, it's much clearer to chomp the whole array once you're sure no new elements are coming to it, rather then chomping its elements again and again.

As noted in the comments, whe `while (<STOPWORDS>)` loop doesn't execute, as you exhaust the filehandle by reading from it in list context on the previous line.

You haven't provided example input. If you want to exclude stopwords from a file of words, it's OK, but if you want to process a real text, you'll have to do more work to find the occurrences of the stopwords: they can have different case, and they aren't separated by whitespace only, there's punctuation, too.

You can start from here:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $STOP, 'stop-ats' or die "Can't Open: $!\n";
my %stops;
while (<$STOP>) {
    chomp;
    $stops{$_} = 1;
}

open my $TEXT, '<', 'ats' or die "Cannot open FILE: $!";
while (<$TEXT>) {
    my @words = split /([[:alpha:]]+)/;
    for my $word (@words) {
        print $word unless $stops{ lc $word };
    }
}
```